# What’s the best way to return a function when calling a function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I want to return a function to a function expression. I am unsure the best way to go about it.

```
const btn = document.querySelector(‘#btn’);
const textValue = document.querySelector(#textBox);

var jobQuestion =
  btn.addEventListener(click, function() {
      interviewQuestion(textValue);
  })

function interviewQuestion(job) {
  if (job.value === “driver”) {
    return function() {
      console.log(“have you had a speeding fine before”);
    }
  } else if (job.value === “doctor”) {
    return function() {
      console.log(“what university did you go to ? ”)
    }
  }
}

jobQuestion();
```

The textValue is an input type text box. Is this a legitimate way to do it? So sorry about the layout. My wife is on the laptop for work so I’ve had a nightmare doing this on my phone. Thanks all

Comment: But why do you return a function? Is this really necessary? In this specific situation do you need to return a function?

Comment: No , there is no explicit return from `addEventListener()` and you should be getting an error that 
*"jobQuestion is not a function"*. Not really sure what you are hoping to accomplish with `jobQuestion()`

Comment: I agree i dont the need to do it. I’m just trying to understand concepts at the moment. The jobQuestion() is designed to invoke the function that I returned from the interviewQuestion function. I’ve clearly misunderstood this! How can I read the input of a textbox and pass it as an argument to a function through an event listener and then have it return a function ? Is this possible?

Comment: You can invoke the returned function `interviewQuestion(textValue)()// <== () to invoke` . Just not seeing in the primitive use case shown why you would need it or what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Note your original concept wouldn't take into consideration that the event has to occur before you evaluate what user has changed value to

Comment: If I call interviewQuestion(textValue) without assigning the value to an event listener then won’t the function invoke upon the page loading and the value of the text box be empty?

Comment: Correct... the `()` would be added in same calling context inside the event handler. But without a more valid reason to do this I think you've just gone down a bit of a weird rabbit hole

Comment: Thanks for your help. I started learning only a few months ago. I watched a tutorial and he was returning functions to the calling function, the function that was returned back depended on what the argument “job” was passed! But I thought in reality the user would type in what their job is , I wanted to assign an event Listener to the textbox and then return a function that way instead of back to the function expression that invoked it with the argument that we out in. My thoughts were, there’s no good us passing up a value as an argument, surely the user input would be more realistic?